# When I install Apache Zeppelin in my local machine [Windows 11], The Zeppelin server is started, but UI is not loaded. It throws angular/dist 404 err

Tags: installation, git-bash, apache-zeppelin, windows-11

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PRIYA\Downloads\zeppelin-0.11.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.11.0-bin-all\zeppelin-0.11.0-bin-all\bin\zeppelin-web-angular\dist
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:670)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.doStart(TimedHandler.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:262)
INFO [2024-03-03 10:46:35,251] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:333) - Started ServerConnector@19fcf7f{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8080}
INFO [2024-03-03 10:46:35,251] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:415) - Started @7546ms
INFO [2024-03-03 10:46:35,252] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:271) - Done, zeppelin server started
INFO [2024-03-03 10:46:41,437] ({qtp17796611-17} NotebookServer.java[onOpen]:256) - Open connection to /127.0.0.1:58525 with Session: WebSocketSession[websocket=JsrAnnotatedEventDriver[websocket=org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@10d2164],behavior=SERVER,connection=WebSocketServerConnection@12ba3fc::SocketChannelEndPoint@1e2cc13{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:58525,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/300000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->WebSocketServerConnection@12ba3fc[s=ConnectionState@2df0f3[OPENING],f=Flusher@c4d348[IDLE][queueSize=0,aggregateSize=-1,terminated=null],g=Generator[SERVER,validating,+rsv1],p=Parser@1e1a56b[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null]],remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@1ecaec0[batching=true],incoming=JsrAnnotatedEventDriver[websocket=org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@10d2164],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[permessage-deflate],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension]], config: [Origin, javax.websocket.endpoint.localAddress, javax.websocket.upgrade.locales, javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress, X-Watcher-Key]

I want to install Zeppelin in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by creating the path as it says in bin\:
*\bin\zeppelin-web-angular\dist*

Then I copied .war file **zeppelin-web-angular-0.11.0.war** to *dist\*. You need to extract this, I used Peazip to extract it.

After extracting success, try running it again. It works for me.